# How can I escape certain characters while using python's urllib.urlencode()?

Tags: python, urllib, urlencode

I have a dictionary that I want to urlencode as query parameters.
The server that I am hitting expects the the query to look like this: `http://www.example.com?A=B,C`

But when I try to use `urllib.urlencode` to build the URL, I find that the comma gets turned into `%2C`:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlencode({"A":"B,C"})
'A=B%2CC'
```

Is there any way I can escape the comma so that `urlencode` treats it like a normal character?

If not, how can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding the `query params` as a string before hitting the endpoint.

I have used `requests` for making a request.

For example:

```py
GET Request

import requests

url = "https://www.example.com/?"
query = "A=B,C"

url_final = url + query

url  = requests.get(url_final)

print(url.url)
# https://www.example.com/?A=B,C
```

The comma (along with some other characters) is defined in [RFC 3986](http://pretty-rfc.herokuapp.com/RFC3986#reserved) as a reserved character. This means the comma has defined meaning at various parts in a URL, and if it is not being used in that context it needs to be percent-encoded.

That said, the [query parameter](http://pretty-rfc.herokuapp.com/RFC3986#query) doesn't give the comma any special syntax, so in query parameters, we probably shouldn't be encoding it. That said, it's not entirely Requests' fault: the parameters are encoded using [`urllib.urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib#urllib.urlencode), which is what is percent-encoding the query parameters.

This isn't easy to fix though, because some web services use `,` and some use `%2C`, and neither is wrong. You might just have to handle this encoding yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You can escape certain characters by specifying them explicitly as safe argument value

```
urllib.quote(str, safe='~()*!.\'')
```

More : https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote

Comment: In my case, what should the value of `str` be? `urllib.quote(urllib.urlencode({"A":"B,C"}), safe=',')` does not give the correct answer.

Comment: Also, `urllib.urlencode({"A": urllib.quote("B,C", safe=',')})` does not give the correct answer. So I am not sure what your answer means or how to use it. Please clarify.

Comment: My bad, you cannot escape characters while encoding a dictionary in Py2, although you can use an ugly hack `str.replace("%2C",",")` 

In Py3 however, `urllib.parse.urlencode({"hello":"w,b"},safe=",")`